# 1980s Commodore 64 game about flying toward tower

Tags: identify-this-game

Wondering if anyone can help me shed some light on this vague memory I have as a kid. I'm trying to recall a particular Commodore 64/128 game - here's what I can remember:

- You flew some sort of hovercraft/tank/ship (definitely futuristic, not present-day) across a flat field towards a dark rectangular tower on the horizon.
- I'm pretty sure it was presented in a third-person point of view, directly behind the ship, with the flat horizon in the middle of the screen
- As you approached the tower, it would slowly get larger and larger - not sure what happened when you reached it
- I think maybe the sky would change shades as it got 'later' or you got closer to the tower.
- I think you could only 'strafe' left and right, and maybe slightly forward and backward - i.e. you were always heading towards the 'horizon' and the tower
- There were definitely some sort of powerups you could fly over, that would maybe give you shields, fuel, or ammo? They were represented as sort of 'discs' that kind of looked like whirlpools
- I believe the field you flew across was green - may have had obstacles or something to avoid
- I assume you shot incoming enemies with lasers or something, but I don't really remember

The one thing that stands out is how the tower got larger as you approached the horizon. It sticks in my mind because it was very similar to when I rode my bicycle across Kansas - long flat horizon with the next town's grain silo in the distance, that would grow as you approached it!

I've scoured the internet for all the search terms I can think of, and have come up empty. Anybody have some guesses?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It sounds a lot like the game [Stealth](https://www.mobygames.com/game/c64/stealth), by Brøderbund, released in November 1984:

> You are flying above the land in a stealth airplane. You are trying to
> destroy the tower of darkness which is a distance of 9999 meters away.
> Destroy enemy military radar, bunkers,etc; to get more points. Use
> yellow energy fields for increasing your fuel level, but avoid the red
> energy fields. Once you destroy the Tower, you go onto a tougher level
> with the same basic objective.

[Here is a longplay video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6c4elSgajg), also [available](https://archive.org/details/C64Videoarchive200-50longplays_part1) in the Internet Archive.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds to me like [Starglider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-IGDKtER2M), one of my two favorite games for the Commodore. The towers in the game flank energy rails, which are used to charge up the spacecraft. Interesting note, this game came bundled with [a novel](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/52007803-starglider).

[Here is a video of the gameplay.](https://youtu.be/o-IGDKtER2M?t=442)

[image: Video of Starglider gameplay]

Answer (score 3):

The description is only half-right for [Rescue On Fractalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_on_Fractalus!) but maybe it's the one. The towers in Rescue On Fractalus are enemy turrets, which need to be destroyed.

[Here is some gameplay](https://youtu.be/FbZ-chrOgGg?t=175)

[image: Screenshot of Rescue on Fractalus]

Comment: That's pretty amazing.

Comment: better framerate on the Atari 8bit though ;)