# Space Game from early 1980s with landing on planets, refueling, and aliens

Tags: identify-this-game

I remember when I was really young, I had a friend who would play a game on his TV (so it was probably on a console) which was **so incredibly frightening** that I couldn't even watch, although I'm sure I would laugh now.

The game was played by flying a space ship. You could land on planets to refuel. I believe that during the landing sequence you could see out of the cockpit and you'd see the horizon slowly climb up as you flew down. The entire game may have been played from the point of view of the cockpit but I'm not certain.

Landing seemed to be a gamble - sometimes you would refuel, but sometimes an alien face would appear just outside of the cockpit. I suppose when this happened you would somehow be penalized but I don't remember for sure. If my friend was playing this game, I'd run into his kitchen whenever he'd land to avoid another possible encounter.

I believe I saw this game around 1985 so it must have been made before then. Am I remembering this accurately? What game could this be?

Comment: Please try https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/

Comment: Why the redirect/downvote? I've seen others use the `identify-this-game` tag here...

Comment: Personally, I don't mind [tag:identify-this-game] questions here; it's that in my experience, the more focused Reddit community is much more helpful.

Comment: I'm not voting to close because the odd question like this isn't doing any real harm _at the moment,_ but we have had [extensive discussion](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/779/7208) about these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 4):

I found this in the related section:

[1980s Commodore 64 game about flying toward tower](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16647/1980s-commodore-64-game-about-flying-toward-tower?rq=1)

It's the 2nd game mentioned there - Rescue on Fractalus

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_on_Fractalus!

I watched the video and the alien still scared me!

Comment: According to head developer David Fox, this shock moment made Rescue on Fractalus! "the first computer game to really scare people". -- [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_on_Fractalus!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rescue_on_Fractalus!) (Also, including that mechanic was apparently suggested by George Lucas himself.)